# How to update the scattergraph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jsfiddle, scatter-plot

I have this table and chart with scattergraph:

https://jsfiddle.net/horacebury/bygscx8b/6/

And I'm trying to update the positions of the scatter dots when the values in the second table column change.

Based on this SO I thought I could just use a single line (as I'm not changing the number of points, just their positions):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16071155/71376

However, this code:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  });
```

Is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that:

`svg.selectAll("circle")` is not a typical selection as you have redefined `svg` to be a transition rather than a generic selection:

```
 var svg = d3.select("#chart").transition();
```

Any selection using this `svg` variable will return a transition ([from the API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition)), for example with `transition.selectAll()`:

> For each selected element, selects all descendant elements that match
>   the specified selector string, if any, and returns a transition on the
>   resulting selection.

For transitions, the `.data` method is not available.

If you use `d3.selectAll('circle')` you will have more success. Alternatively, you could drop the `.transition()` when you define `svg` and apply it only to individual elements:

```
var svg = d3.select('#chart');

svg.select(".line").transition() 
  .duration(1000).attr("d", valueline(data));

...
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmztp1kf/1/) taking the latter approach.

---

Also, for your update transition you might want to change scale and values you are using to get your new x,y values (to match your variable names):

```
    //Update all circles
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.close);
      });
  }
```